automorphisms of real algebra $\mathbb{C}$
I have this interesting question about automorphisms of real algebra $\mathbb{C}$.
Firstly, I showed that $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\varphi(z)=\overline{z}$ is an automorphism of real algebra $\mathbb{C}$. Next, I want to show that this function and the identity automorphism on $\mathbb{C}$ are the only one.
My idea was to somehow argue that an automophism of real algebra $\mathbb{C}$ is completely determined by the image of $i$. But how to even show this in general? Any idea? Can we maybe determine this automorphism by the image of a basis and why (if possibly yes)?
Note: I found a similar question here: Prove that conjugation $\tau_2: z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is an automorphism of the real algebra $\mathbb{C}$., but here this was not answered ...

If $\varphi$ is an real automorphism of $\mathbb C$, then $\varphi(x) = x$ for each $x \in \mathbb R$.  Since each complex number $z$ is equal to $a+bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, this means that $$\varphi(z) = \varphi(a+bi) = \varphi(a) + \varphi(bi) = \varphi(a) + \varphi(i) \varphi(b) = a + \varphi(i)b.$$
So, $\varphi$ is completely determined by where it sends $i$.  You can finish by arguing that either $\varphi(i) = i$ or $\varphi(i) = -i$.

May I just ask you why it follows that $\varphi(i)=i$ or $\varphi(i)=-i$? From where exactly?

That's what you have to figure out.  Hint: what equation does $\varphi(i)$ satisfy?

But from letting $a=0,b=1$ in upper equation I get $\varphi(i)=\varphi(i)$. This equation only tells me that $\varphi$ is completely determined by $i$ ... Just like you wrote, I agree with that.

In other words, I still can't see how this solves my exercise.

Because $\phi$ is an automorphism, $\phi(i)^2 = \phi(i^2) = \phi(-1) = -1$.

@eti902 You should have left this for Markus!

In other words, if $\varphi$ is an automorphism, it swaps around the solutions of polynomial equations such as $x^2+1$.  This principle limits the possibilities for such automorphisms, and is the reason Galois theory works.
